# PANDAS DROP ROWS based on filtered items, my solution - not satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, text-analysis

I am working on cleaning a list domain names.

I want to drop certain rows that "fit" a criteria. I have succeeded in identifying the first criteria, the second will be easy to do.

However, I cannot drop the rows. I have tried several solution but the best I have is the following.

```
from wordsegment import segment
import pandas as pd

def assignname():
    dfr = pd.read_csv('data.net.date.csv')

    for domainwtld in dfr.domain:
        dprice = dfr.price
        domainwotld = domainwtld.replace(".net", "")
        seperate = wordsegment.segment(domainwotld)
        dlnt = (min(seperate, key=len))
        slnt = len(dlnt)
        if slnt <= 1:
            baddomains = domainwtld
            a = dfr.loc[dfr['domain'] < (baddomains)]
            print (a)
```

When I run this code, I receive a output that after dropping the first item in  "baddomains", prints the entire item in "dfr". It does this until the loop is complete.

How can I can filter the "original" csv file based on baddomains?

Comment: you might try using .isin if dfr['domain'] is an exact match to your baddomains dfr.loc[~dfr['domain'].isin(baddomains_list)]

Comment: thanks but TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

Comment: Perhaps you can supply some sample data?

Comment: [link]https://www.mediafire.com/?sa4ifz8rixe7m8u[/link]

Comment: My exampled uses 'baddomains_list' -- a new variable. I presumed you would generate this list on your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from wordsegment import segment
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://download1474.mediafire.com/3ndc8vevwtng/sa4ifz8rixe7m8u/data.net.date+%285%29.csv'
dfr = pd.read_csv(url)
dfr['domain'] = dfr.domain.str.replace(".net", "")
dfr['words'] = df.domain.apply(segment)
good_domains = dfr[dfr.words.apply(lambda words: len(min(words, key=len))) > 1]
bad_domains = dfr[~dfr.domain.isin(good_domains.domain)]

>>> bad_domains
        domain  price           words
2        keeng    700       [keen, g]
14       ymall    777       [y, mall]
22       idisc    850       [i, disc]
26      borsen    877      [borse, n]
38    cellacom    895  [cell, a, com]
51     iwealth    999     [i, wealth]
96     iplayer   1500     [i, player]
116  mcommerce   2000   [m, commerce]
118      apico   2052       [a, pico]
134     epharm   2500      [e, pharm]
139     ionica   2579      [ionic, a]
153    kasiino   2999   [kasi, in, o]
155    alpadia   3000   [al, padi, a]
158   similans   3152    [similan, s]
163    ifuture   3499     [i, future]

>>> bad_domains.domain.tolist()
['keeng',
 'ymall',
 'idisc',
 'borsen',
 'cellacom',
 'iwealth',
 'iplayer',
 'mcommerce',
 'apico',
 'epharm',
 'ionica',
 'kasiino',
 'alpadia',
 'similans',
 'ifuture']
```

Comment: Thanks alot, in my moment of frustration - I failed to explain their is a master list. How, do I use this list to get a clean master list for my data set.

Comment: I was able to somehow do this with my terrible code, this was the result.